# Деплой NodeJS сервиса на второй компьютер в локальной сети

Tags: node.js, windows, клиент-сервер, развертывание

у меня есть два компьютера с windows 10 pro, 2й пк я использую как сервер, они оба подключены к одному маршрутизатору, весь локалхост настроен и локал айпи - статичные

И я бы хотел нажимать на 1й пк команду, и через какое-то время чувствовать новый код уже на 2м пк, естественно с pm2, который будет поддерживать жизнь в ядр-*loop*-е, и желательно чтобы я мог [видеть ~`pm2 status` и управлять всеми нодами] из-вне 2го пк, например на сайте *или хоть где*

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как это всё грамотно реализовать и следовательно спросить, потому-что хотелось бы не подключать миллион всего - по типу: git(плюс логин в нём), linux bash, docker(в принципе - можно, если это всё решит), ssh и остальное

Как "принимать" деплой на сервере и далее развертывать его, без танцев с бубном, клонированием репы и тд

Comment: Ну, копировать - `robocopy`. Ставить софт - ну я использую `ansible`, но тогда нужна тачка с линуксом. Можно с `psexec` поизвращаться.

Comment: @donRumata мне кажется проще git pull делать при помощи tg бота, так же им все остальное делать

Comment: Ну автоматизация в винде - это боль и костыли. Я бы тебе советовал или завести виртуалку на линуксе или вторую тачку переставить на линукс или типа того.

Comment: Стоп. ТГ-бот для деплоя на соседнюю тачку в локалке? Ого!